# Subir imagen por AJAX con evento onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero poder subir una imagen al servidor con el evento `onchange` pero no consigo hacerme con ello.

**En mi vista**

```
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="imageFile"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $("#imageFile").on('change', (function (e) { // Why it doesn't work?
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
      url: "/guardar_logo_cliente",
      type: "POST",
      data: new FormData(),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) {
                    
      },
      error: function () {
     }
   });
 }));
 });
```

**En mi controlador**

```
public function guardar_logo_cliente(Request $request)
{
    $model = $request->image;
    
    $name = $model->getClientOriginalName();
    $model_name  = $data['name']. '-'. $name;
    $model->move(base_path('public/images/logos_presupuestos/'), $model_name);
    return $model;
}
```

Pero no va bien, recibo esto:

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Comment: tiene el `new FormData()` vacio.... :v

Comment: Hola @Bryro antes tenia `new FormData(this),` pero sin éxito

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164365/how-to-send-image-to-php-file-using-ajax